# Car still pulling to right after 3 wheel alignment

Tags: honda, accord, alignment

I had subframe replaced on a 2008 Honda Accord after my son hit a curb while turning. The car is still pulling to the right we’ve had 3 wheel alignments and the last place told me the right front wheel cannot be adjusted because something is bent which is causing the pull however he was not sure what it could be. We’ve already spent enough money and really want to get this repaired ASAP any suggestions of what this could be? It also makes a low squealing
noise when driving but stops when you break

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was it a new or used subframe? Was it just the subframe which was replaced, or did you have more parts replaced? Did the technician suggest what parts might be bent?

Comment: Any competent alignment shop should be able to diagnose and replace a bent or damaged part that is preventing aligning the wheels.  Take it somewhere else.

Comment: It was a new subframe and control arm that was also new that was replaced. I’ve taken it to 3 different places who do alignments and unfortunately none of those places know what is bent

Comment: The place I took it today said it could possibly be strut